# Question about the Facebook SDK for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, fbconnect

Today, I have downloaded the last version of the Facebook API for iPhone. I have integrated it to my project with no problem. But there are some things very different to the older versions, for example:

There is no log in dialog, on this version when I tap the Log In button, the sdk takes me to Safari, then I log in and then it back to the app. My question is: is that ok? is there some way to show the log in dialog like on the older version?

Comment: Note sure about it so putting it as a comment...authorize function in facebook.m file has a boolean argument for that..I thing you need to change that variable boolean value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. that is absolutely okay. In that provide proper credentials and it will confirm for authorization for the application. Once user clicks okay it will be returned back to the application. You need to change your .plist file and provide your application id in that. flow is like

```
 URL Types              :
     ITEM 0             :
       URL Identifier   :
       URL Schemes      :
         Item 0         : fb **Your Application ID of Facebook** (without space with FB)
```

Based on that it will return to your application. Hope it helps.